# Name for a module from which the program is run

Tags: python

Is there a technical name for a module or file from which the code is run?

I am asked to write some code to integrate both numerically and with fourier analysis.  I have to prove that this code works to give the e-field and the voltage at a p-n junction.

To do this I have created 7 modules, Run.py, ODESolver.py, NODESolver.py, FODESolver.py, Functions.py, BinFunction.py, UserInput.py.

In order to demonstrate the code the module Run.py must be called in the terminal, it then calls whatever else it needs depending on user inputs.

The module called Run.py is clearly special. Is there a technical name for it?

EDIT:
I am not looking for a file name - rather a way to refer to the module in the report. (i.e. this is the XYZ module of the program). Though its quite possible that there is a naming convention for the file name.

Comment: Why do you need to know this? You can call it `main script`, for example, or you can call it barack_merkel or something similar.

Comment: I need to know this is that I can refer to it correctly in a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python the root module that is run and selects what else to run is always `__main__` and is referred to as "main" - note that if each of the sub modules can also be run independently it may have its own "main" protected with `if __name__ == "__main__:`

Of course you can also refer to it as your "User Interface" as that is what it is.

Comment: So if I was writing a report and I wanted to refer to this module I could say "This is my **main** module called Run.py, it is the module that should be used to run the code for this demonstration."?

Comment: Yes, exactly or you could say "the main User Interface is run from Run.py while testing can be performed by running the modules individually"

Answer (score 2):

Python has a special feature, in that if you call your main file `__main__.py`, you can give the directory containing your program to python, and it will execute `__main__.py`. E.g. directory tree:

```
program
  |- __main__.py
  |- a_module.py
  \- another_module.py
```

You can do:

```
$ python program
```

And `__main__.py` will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't NEED a special name for it but there are some programming standards. Some are called *main*.py and many are just run. If you create and .exe or .app file it doesn't mater. It is good practise, especially in open source.